# How to make empty server response to be treated as failure in ExtJS form submit

Tags: ajax, json, forms, extjs4

I have the login form in ExtJS 4 MVC architecture style. That is, I have one controller and one view.

The view file (only component creation part is shown):

```js
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {border:false, baseCls: 'x-plain', flex:8}, // 13/8 - is golden ratio (approx.)
        {
            border: false,
            baseCls: 'x-plain',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                pack: 'center',
                align: 'center'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    url: 'http://localhost/my_site/login.php',
                    title: 'login_form_title',
                    bodyPadding: 5,
                    width: 280,

                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        labelWidth: 90,
                        anchor: '100%'
                    },

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'username',
                            fieldLabel: 'username',
                            allowBlank: false
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            inputType: 'password',
                            name: 'password',
                            fieldLabel: 'password',
                            allowBlank: false
                        },
                        {
                            border: false,
                            baseCls: 'x-plain',
                            layout: {
                                type: 'hbox',
                                pack: 'center',
                                align: 'center'
                            },
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    formBind: true,
                                    disabled: true,
                                    text: 'login',
                                    action: 'login'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {border:false, baseCls: 'x-plain', flex:13} // 13/8 - is golden ratio (approx.)
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

In my controller I've bind login button onclick to some function and inside that function I am submitting the form to server with this piece of code:

```js
oForm.submit({
    success: function(form, action) {
        console.log('success');
    },

    failure: function(form, action) {
        console.log(action.failureType);
    }
});
```

And this is `http://localhost/my_site/login.php`

```php
<?php
exit;
```

When I am pressing login button I see `success` in developer console. Question is the following:

1. Is it possible to make empty response to be considered as `failure`, that is, to make developer console to log some `failureType` in that case.
2. Why empty response is considered as `success`? Links to official documentation or to other resources will be very welcome.

When using the following `http://localhost/my_site/login.php`, I get `server` in developer console, which is correct.

```php
<?php
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'success'=>false, 
        'errors' => array(
            'reason' => 'Invalid username or password'
        )
    )
);
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is, to set the HTTP header for the response! Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) or [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Basically you can say, if the status code of the response is not "200 Success" than ExtJS will call the failure method!

In your case you should do following:

```
<?php
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Top Secret Files"');
header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
?>
```

Also you should set the correct content type. Default is "text/plain" but in you case you should set it to "application/json". If you don't set it to application/json you have to parse the response manually, otherwise ExtJS will do it for you.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

Here you find a very good [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/) about HTTP headers!
And [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch07_05.htm) you have an example in PHP!

I use C# on the server-side, so I don't know the actual php-code, but as long as the HTTP header is **200 OK** Ext-JS will call the success-method!

Comment: I've tried to set `header('Content-type: application/json');`, but without any effect. Empty response with `Content-type: application/json` header is still considered as `success`.

Comment: Use FireBug or Chrome and look in the network tab! Are you getting the response-header with the error-number you have set?? You should try another http-status (Maybe your local WebServer doesn't support this number)

Comment: thanks for answering.  the problem is that I can get empty response only when I have some unpredicted critical error in server-side code. I don't know when this can happen,  that's why I can't set error header code at that time. Well,  in php I can define custom error handler,  and set error code there,  but I worry that will not cover all possible cases when empty response can happen. +1 for idea, though!

Comment: the same problem is with ajax calls using Ext.Ajax. I don't know how let Ext.Ajax know,  that my response should be only valid json code, and any other responses should be treated as failures.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to make empty response to be considered as `failure`, that is, to make developer console to log some
>      `failureType` in that case.
> 2. Why empty response is considered as `success`? Links to official documentation or to other resources will be very welcome.

`Ext.form.submit()` is marked as failed on the basis of following response -

```
{
    success: false,
    errors: {
        clientCode: "Client not found",
        portOfLoading: "This field must not be null"
    }
}
```

Empty response is not considered as failure of request as long as it does not contain `success:false`

you can find out more about this [Here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit)

Comment: thanks for reply, but the way to avoid such behavior is still unclear for me. empty response is not a valid json and should be treated as failure. I found nothing about empty responses in official documentation.